# Use getItemType in List View

Tags: android, listview

I want to add dynamic header in a list view, i.e dynamic data for the list view header which will come from the parsed information at the time of loading the list view.

**Please read my scenario below. It is must to understand my problem.**

Here i am doing it like this using `getItemType` for the position 0 of the list view.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){

        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if(type==TYPE_HEADER){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_basket_small_item, parent,false);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_basket_small_item, parent,false);

            holder.tv_price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
            holder.tv_distance = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_distance);
            holder.img_brandLogo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_brandlogo_top);
            holder.img_beerCanLogo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_beerCan);
            holder.click4map = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_click_for_map);
            holder.offers = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_my_basket_offers);
        }
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

My problem is that I want to show the fixed Header with dynamic data plus the list view rows (total number of `arraylist` size). 
Right now it is working for one row less, as one row is occupied by the list view header.

**Scenario :
 for example 4 list view rows are coming (without header)
When I use header, again 4 rows are coming, I just want that when I use header, 1 header plus 4 rows should come.**

Hope you understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should add header by calling:

```
<ListView>.addHeaderView(<HeaderView>,null, false);
```

And only set items using adapter.

in your current implementation u can override:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return <list>.size()+1;
}
```

Comment: But the data of the header should be dynamic, that I have to change it in the adapter class

Comment: post your complete adapter. I don't see you setting any data that you have posted. But overriding getCount should work in your case

Answer (score 1):

There is another approach to this issue - every view item contains header with visibility being managed in getView method.
Your list item layout file may look like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:id="headerTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and getView() may look like this:

```
    if(converView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_basket_small_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.header = convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        holder.headerTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);
        holder.tv_price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        holder.tv_distance = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_distance);
        holder.img_brandLogo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_brandlogo_top);
        holder.img_beerCanLogo = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_beerCan);
        holder.click4map = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_click_for_map);
        holder.offers = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_my_basket_offers);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if(type==TYPE_HEADER){
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.SHOW);
        holder.headerTextView.setText("Header");
    }else{
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    ...
```